# Image does not loaded and throwingjava.net.MalformedURLException

Tags: android, json

i am parsing a json string from which i get the url of image. then i pass that url to a method to get the image and display it in an imageview but the image does not loaded and throws an exception of java.net.MalformedURLException. when i try to pass the image url directly to the method then it gets loaded. so i dont know where is the error.  Any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance. my code is below

```
public class CompanyDetailActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView coverimage;
    ImageView profileimage;
    TextView fullname;
    TextView tagline;
    TextView industry;
    TextView teamsize;
    TextView about;
    TextView year;
    TextView location;

    String Coverimage;
    String Profimage;
    String Fullname;
    String Tagline;
    String Industry;
    String Teamsize;
    String About;
    String Year;
    String Location;

    // Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.companydetails);

        coverimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.CoverImage);
        profileimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ProfileImage);
        fullname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.FullName);
        tagline = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TagLine);
        industry = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.IndustryName);
        teamsize = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TeamSize);
        about = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CompanyAbout);
        year = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.FoundYear);
        location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Location);

        new DetailsAsynTask()
                .execute("http://www.mygmn.com/joblink/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=joblink_searchcompanies&company_id=1180");

        GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
        task.execute(Coverimage);

    }

    public class DetailsAsynTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            try {

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(arg0[0]);

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (status == 200) {
                    // to get response
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONObject MainObject = jObj.getJSONObject("data");
                    CompanyDetailsModel company = new CompanyDetailsModel();
                    Coverimage = company.setCoverImage(MainObject
                            .getString("cove_img"));

                    Profimage = company.setCompanyProfPicture(MainObject
                            .getString("company_profile_picture"));

                    Fullname = company.setCompanyFullName(MainObject
                            .getString("company_full_name"));

                    Tagline = company.setComapnyTagLine(MainObject
                            .getString("company_tagline"));
                    Industry = company.setCompanyInustry(MainObject
                            .getString("company_industry"));
                    Teamsize = company.setCompanyTeamSize(MainObject
                            .getString("company_teamsize"));
                    About = company.setCompanyAbout(MainObject
                            .getString("company_about"));
                    Year = company.setCompanyFoundYear(MainObject
                            .getString("company_foundyear"));
                    Location = company.setCompanyLocation(MainObject
                            .getString("company location"));

                    return true;
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (result == false) {

            } else {

                fullname.setText(Fullname);
                tagline.setText(Tagline);
                industry.setText(Industry);
                teamsize.setText(Teamsize);
                about.setText(About);
                year.setText(Year);
                location.setText(Location);

            }
        }

    }

    private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            Bitmap map = null;
            for (String url : urls) {
                map = downloadImage(url);
            }

            return map;
        }

        // Sets the Bitmap returned by doInBackground
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            coverimage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }

        // Creates Bitmap from InputStream and returns it
        private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            InputStream stream = null;
            BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

            try {
                stream = getHttpConnection(url);
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, bmOptions);
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

        // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
        private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
                throws IOException {
            InputStream stream = null;
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

            try {
                HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
                httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConnection.connect();

                if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return stream;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: try with this:  http://mygmn.com/joblink/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=joblink_searchcompanies&company_id=1180  . Exclude: "www. " from "www.mygmn.com"

Comment: user3467204 i dont know what you mean.. the data is the same on the server. i have checked the data i saved in the variables in logcat.

Comment: your server is responding with properly formed url for image. but couldn't understand how you are loading the image in imageview

Comment: In this section :  new DetailsAsynTask()
            .execute("http://www.mygmn.com/joblink/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=joblink_searchcompanies&company_id=1180");
Remove "www." and then try to run it .

Comment: Post full Logcat in your question and not in comments, please.

Comment: user3467204 i tried the same as you told but the problem remains the same

Comment: ok . Your problem is in the image download url .Can You show us what is the url that you are using to download images.

Comment: Amit K. Saha please tell me the correct way how can i load the it in imageview if you know any other way

Comment: user3467204 click on the web service url...there you can find the url of image i want to load.

Comment: user3467204 the url from which i want to download the data is given the  DetailsAsynTask() .execute method

Comment: You can try one more thing: Move this code :    GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
        task.execute(Coverimage); to the ofPostExecute  Method of your Details asynctask .

Comment: user3467204 you exactly diagnose the problem. got the image. thanks for your support...

Comment: ok I am posting this as answer with explanation . Mark it as right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running two asynctasks inside onCreate() method .As these are asynchronous your GetXMLTask was executed with String CoverImage as null .
So , moving this code :

```
GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask(); 
task.execute(Coverimage);
```

to the `onPostExecute()` Method of your Details asynctask will solve the problem .

Answer (score 1):

java.net.MalformedURLException can come due to security reason .you have to add http:// or https:// with your url images.

Answer (score 0):

ok, use this code

```
public class ImageLoading {

public enum BitmapManager {  
    INSTANCE;  

    private final Map<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> cache;  
    private final ExecutorService pool;  
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections  
            .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());  
    private Bitmap placeholder;  

    BitmapManager() {  
        cache = new HashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>>();  
        pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);  
    }  

    public void setPlaceholder(Bitmap bmp) {  
        placeholder = bmp;  
    }  


    public Bitmap getBitmapFromCache(String url) {  
        if (cache.containsKey(url)) {  
            return cache.get(url).get();  
        } 
        return null;  
    }  

    public void queueJob(final String url, final ImageView imageView,  
            final int width, final int height) {  
        /* Create handler in UI thread. */  
        final Handler handler = new Handler() {  
            @Override  
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {  
                String tag = imageViews.get(imageView);  
                if (tag != null && tag.equals(url)) {  
                    if (msg.obj != null) {  
                        imageView.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) msg.obj);  
                    } else {  
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(placeholder);  
                        Log.d(null, "fail " + url);  
                    }  
                }  
            }  
        };  

        pool.submit(new Runnable() {  
            @Override  
            public void run() {  
                final Bitmap bmp = downloadBitmap(url, width, height);  
                Message message = Message.obtain();  
                message.obj = bmp;  
                Log.d(null, "Item downloaded: " + url);  

                handler.sendMessage(message);  
            }  
        });  
    }  

    public void loadBitmap(final String url, final ImageView imageView,  
            final int width, final int height) {  
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);  
        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromCache(url);  

        // check in UI thread, so no concurrency issues  
        if (bitmap != null) {  
            Log.d(null, "Item loaded from cache: " + url);  
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);  
        } else {  
            imageView.setImageBitmap(placeholder);  
            queueJob(url, imageView, width, height);  
        }  
    }  

    private Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url, int width, int height) {  
        try {  
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(  
                    url).getContent());  
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);  
            cache.put(url, new SoftReference<Bitmap>(bitmap));  
            return bitmap;  
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  

        return null;  
    }  
}
```

Directly use this code,and where you are using downloading code ,use this code
    ImageLoading.BitmapManager.INSTANCE.loadBitmap("http://"+image, holder.img, 150, 180);

Comment: This is ImageView object.

Comment: Sorry i dont have a another use full answer for you.Try this code again and again hope you will get answer

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is okay from your server response. Instead of loading the image manually try [Picasso Library](http://Try%20Picasso%20library%20http://square.github.io/picasso/%20to%20load%20image%20url%20into%20imageview)

with this library, you will just need to do-

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```